# Starting a running training program

Tags: running, running-training-plan

I need help for some website or video etc so that i can start a jogging or running program...
Although i do workout regularly.
Some things i have heard are like interval running, increasing pace slowly
should one land on front foot back foot or middle , there are many variants
and how much time intially to start, how much distance ?
Something related to details of preventing common running injuries like shin splints etc

Thanks

Comment: Best place to start is just to start! What have you done so far?

Comment: Generallly i do workout with dumbells and HIIT

Comment: Have completed one round of LIIFT4 of beachbody

Comment: Yes that ses good